# Is there any app that returns a list of cities in Europe for direct train travel by entering the departure city?

Tags: trains, europe, online-resources

I'm looking for an app that returns a list of cities for direct train travel in Europe, by entering the departure city.

For example, if I enter Warsaw as an input, the app should return a list of cities where a train travel from Warsaw is available. So it should return Krakow, Poznan, Berlin, etc... for example.

Apps like [GoEuro](https://www.goeuro.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=%5BTrain_02_Gen%5D%7C%7CUSA%3A%20Rail&utm_term=euro+rail&adgroup=Train_02_Gen%7CLoc-EU__%7C__%7C__%7C%7CEN_EU%7CE%7C&content=basic&gclid=Cj0KCQjwlf_MBRDUARIsAD8Gj8BTXbDu7ufI4UKc4NI6E4FlDmQk8CLi-W0Bmh2N3j59QBMVXvXQwawaAqDBEALw_wcB) only show popular destinations, and it includes flights. [RailEurope](https://www.raileurope.com/index.html) and [Loco2](https://loco2.com) don't even show candidates.

Is there such app available?

Comment: Arre you looking for *direct* trains only? If you are willing to accept transfers, there are few destinations in the rail network which are not connected.

Comment: @o.m. I'm looking for direct trains only. I didn't know the transfer trains exist...

Comment: Just to make it easier for you to search, the term used for this kind of search is called "broad search".. in case you didn't know already.

Comment: @Blaszard: "I didn't know the transfer trains exist" - well, as with any means of transportation, you can switch vehicles while underway if no single vehicle brings you all the way. And while, with flights, that is rather limited to transportation related to one "main flight" (in that many flights can be seen as one big flight from an international hub to another one, plus one small flight to get to that hub and another one to get from the destination hub to your actual destination), taking a sequence of trains is very much the default case in train travel.

Comment: The reason you aren't finding anything is probably that nobody but you cares about this. Going from A to B may require changing trains, so what? People care how long it takes and how much it costs, but the number of changes is not a critical criterion.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In that case don't you have to buy two separate tickets? I meant a single ticket, much like the flight. But is it also available? Otherwise if the first train is delayed, I could not get any compensation.

Comment: @Blaszard: The specifics of all of this depend a lot on the exact location and route. However, to name just one example: To get from a city in he South of Germany to a city in the North of Germany, it is well possible that you have to travel on two or three long distance trains, and use only one ticket for all of them (because it's a ticket for the complete route). Furthermore, you either pay the standard price and may take *any* train on the indicated route (making delays a non-issue, ticket-wise), or you pay a discounted price, in which case you have to take a specific train *unless* ...

Comment: ... *the connection breaks due to a delay on one of the booked trains*. But each country in Europe has its own train organisation and rules vary for each of them (or sometimes even depending on train type). As a general rule, I agree with @Gilles that finding out all destinations reachable from a given location without an interchange is not a useful use case for the vast majority of places and train travellers.

Comment: Perhaps I do not get the full sense of your question but in Europe you can virtually travel from X to Y! Of course, connections vary by convenience and easiness. In fact, the major limitations are usually and possibly a prolonged stop waiting for the next train, or a transfer in a big and perhaps unknown city (though it normally happens in Paris, to me. Most transfers, if any, are almost one way to go, by bus or even by feet  5 10'.

Answer (score 7):

There is an exact web app that does this work - https://direkt.bahn.guru.

For example, here is the result of Krakow Glowny as the departure.

[image]

This app only allows you to search by the station, not by the city. So in order to get all the direct trains from one city, you must repeat the search with all the stations available in a city - in the case of Krakow, *Krakow Glowny*, *Krakow Zablocie* and *Krakow Plaszou*.

Answer (score 6):

Deutsche Bahn's website has a [Arrival / Departure lookup](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/bhftafel.exe/en) page, which will show you where all the trains departing from a particular station go to - including intermediate stops as well as final destinations. It works quite well for most of Europe, though it seems to only give you results for 1 hour of departures at a time.

Comment: More national rail and/or rail company websites offer that service. So if you know which country you start from, try if their national site does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check following train websites, you only need to enter your departure city and your arrival city, it take care to search for you all transport connections available (train, bus, ferry, walk)

- [ÖBB](https://www.oebb.at/en/) www.oebb.at/en, Austria, (Better UI/UX but does not consider ferry connections)
- [SBB](https://www.sbb.ch/en/) www.sbb.ch/en, Switzerland
- [DB] www.bahn.com/en , Germany

For most of the journeys you can buy everything in a single ticket that includes all the connections, and if not, get a detailed trip plan.

I recommend also their mobile apps, their are really accurate, show you the preview journey and up to date with possible delays.

Enjoy traveling!

Answer (score -1):

Many booking sites allow you to select an origin, and then the destination menu is auto-filtered to what's available.  (Although on some sites, that includes transfers that can be put on the same ticket.)

Comment: Which websites? I added GoEuro, RailEurope, and Loco2, which are shown on the top of my search results but none gets me the full list of available cities automatically...

Comment: I haven't used one recently, but most train and bus sites I've used do that.  Some though, expect you to type at least one letter before they show you the available destinations that start with that letter.  Both filtering methods do depend on JavaScript.  I know some people turn that off.